# Neon(glowing) Button in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I saw some videos in YouTube about how to make a Neon button in flutter, but i could not find a tutorial about how to make Glowing button in jetpack compose.

can we make a Glowing Button in jetpack compose?

somthing like one of these buttons:

[image]

Comment: Can you attach screenshot of you expectation?

Comment: yeah. I added an image

Comment: Reza you can check this answer out. Since OP asks for only stroke but you can draw a rectangle behind a button as in this answer. I can provide full answer when i'm avilable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72973630/how-to-draw-a-square-with-stroke-and-neon-glow-with-jetpack-compose-canvas. With some tweak you can add glow/dim effect as in this video. https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/35650605/179715223-ba681886-6032-461f-806a-ea6a535d0627.mp4 the drawing glows and dims using an infinite transitition

Comment: Thanks Thracian. it was good. I didn't understand how to add glow by the video. I can't wait to see your full answer. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

I know that I'm a little bit late but...
Based on [how to draw a square with stroke and neon glow with Jetpack Compose Canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72973630/how-to-draw-a-square-with-stroke-and-neon-glow-with-jetpack-compose-canvas) I created the following extension:

```
fun ContentDrawScope.drawNeonStroke(radius: Dp) {
this.drawIntoCanvas {
    val paint =
        Paint().apply {
            style = PaintingStyle.Stroke
            strokeWidth = 20f
        }

    val frameworkPaint =
        paint.asFrameworkPaint()

    val color = Color.Magenta

    this.drawIntoCanvas {
        frameworkPaint.color = color.copy(alpha = 0f).toArgb()
        frameworkPaint.setShadowLayer(
            radius.toPx(), 0f, 0f, color.copy(alpha = .5f).toArgb()
        )
        it.drawRoundRect(
            left = 0f,
            right = size.width,
            bottom = size.height,
            top = 0f,
            radiusY = radius.toPx(),
            radiusX = radius.toPx(),
            paint = paint
        )
        drawRoundRect(
            color = Color.Magenta,
            size = size,
            cornerRadius = CornerRadius(radius.toPx(), radius.toPx()),
            style = Stroke(width = 1.dp.toPx())
        )
      }
   }
}
```

We are drawing here a one border with solid color and second (much wider) with radial gradient.

Then, all what we need to do is draw this on top of our button:

```
            CompositionLocalProvider(
                LocalMinimumTouchTargetEnforcement provides false,
            ) {
                OutlinedButton(
                    onClick = { },
                    modifier = Modifier.drawWithContent {
                        drawContent()
                        drawNeonStroke(radius = 8.dp)
                    },
                    border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Transparent),
                ) {
                    Text(text = "OUTLINED BUTTON", color = Color.Magenta)
                }

                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(20.dp))

                Button(
                    onClick = { },
                    modifier = Modifier.drawWithContent {
                        drawContent()
                        //Draw neon glow on top of your button
                        drawNeonStroke(radius = 8.dp)
                    },
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
                    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = Color.Magenta)
                ) {
                    Text(text = "FILLED BUTTON", color = Color.Black)
                }
            }
```

The above example shows drawing our neon stroke on top of filled and outlined button.

`CompositionLocalProvider` removes the default button padding.

`colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = Color.Magenta)` change the background color of button, you won't need this If your button already has the desired color.

[image: Result]